# How to automatically make Mac shutdown after Time Machine Backup

Tags: macos, time-machine

How can I make my Macbook automatically shutdown after a Time Machine backup?

I have a 40GB worth backup to do but I keep having to cancel it to go to bed. Would be great if I could leave it on to do it overnight.

Any suggestions of how to do this in ML?

Comment: Why do you have to cancel it to go to bed?

Comment: Because I wouldn't want my Macbook on all night incase of overheating

Comment: Once it idles, it will go to sleep. You are overthinking this one.

Comment: Set it to sleep even with power on after X minutes and let it run until done?

Comment: Doesn't sleeping still use a considerable amount of power resources?

Comment: It probably uses more power cold booting your laptop every morning than leaving it to sleep at night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup a crontab to use tmutil through the command line to do a backup and then shutdown. since shutdown requires sudo privs, you have to set your crontab up as sudo.

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Enter your password and then that brings you to edit the contab file

```
shutdown -h now
```

Shutdown does exactly that but with the -h flag, it halts the system (shutdown).
For the shutdown to work, this would have to be setup as an crontab under sudo

```
tmutil startbackup
```

Starts the timemachine backup.

Putting it all together:

```
00 20 ** ** ** tmutil startbackup --block && shutdown -h +5
```

Would do the backup at 10:00pm every day and then shutdown

Comment: Looking at the post by @da4 you could replace rsync with tmutil. I was unaware of their command line tool

Comment: `sudo zsh -c "tmutil startbackup --block && shutdown -h +5"` to run it manually without any additional blocking password prompts. No need to setup crontab, if you don't need it.

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to be able to leave an *existing* backup to complete, so my approach is a little different.

The `backupd` process seems only to be running whilst a backup is underway (and for a minute or two afterwards, from what I've observed) so I logged in as root (so that I can (a) see all users' process and (b) trigger a shutdown) and then polled for the process to finish before shutting down.  So:

```
sudo -s
```

and enter your password to become root, then:

```
while ( ps -ef | grep 'backupd$' ); do echo "Still backing up..."; sleep 60; done; shutdown -h +1
```

to wait for `backupd` to finish and then shut down.  (I used `shutdown -h +1` instead of `shutdown -h now` just to be over-cautious and give it an extra minute to tidy up or whatever before shutting down.)

Comment: Unfortunatelyl, this didn't work for me. Although Time Machine finished the backup, `ps -ef | grep 'backupd$'` returns `0   213     1   0 Wed03PM ??     119:47.66 /System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/backupd`, so the script cannot work. This is Big Sur 11.2.1 (20D74), using an external drive as Time Machine backup drive.

Comment: @MartinBraun Sorry to hear it doesn't work for you.  My Mac can only run up to 10.11.6, sadly, so I can't check that out.  I wonder if anyone else can confirm it doesn't work with that version...?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have already set a destination for your TM, you could open a shell in Terminal (or ssh in), `sudo su` into super-user mode, then run `tmutil startbackup --block;shutdown -h now;exit` which tells TM to begin a backup immediately, turn off the Mac, and exit the shell.  `man tmutil` for more info.

You could also then add this as a launchctl item or even cron it to schedule.

Comment: Be careful with this. I plugged my time machine drive in and ran this command. The time machine backup was already being prepared, so the tmutil errored out (saying a backup was in progress) and then the shutdown command was issued (which froze my laptop for some reason, I had to do a hard reset).

Trying again now with no backup being prepared, fingers crossed!